# Column name not working when placed inside a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please explain why this code is not working?

```
ALTER function sample1 (@col VARCHAR (32), @keyWord VARCHAR (32))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res INT

    SELECT @res = COUNT(*) 
    FROM m_table 
    WHERE @col LIKE 'John Leo'

    RETURN @res
END
```

I noticed that when I hardcoded the column name, it works. but if I use the variable `@var` for it, it returns a value of `0`. Is it because I placed the column name in a variable?

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: You cannot parametrize table or column names

Comment: Is there any possible way to make it work?